# Play 2.5 Migration: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector

Tags: java, playframework

I tried to migrate my Play 2.4.6 project to Play 2.5.8 following the official migration guide: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25

After the Database successfully connects i get the following error message (Full Stacktrace):

```
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at XXX;
[error] application - 

! @71in3ncdp - Internal server error, for (GET) [/de] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:22):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions

1 error]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:180)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:22):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.DatabasePlatform.createDdlHandler(DatabasePlatform.java:209)
    at com.avaje.ebean.dbmigration.model.CurrentModel.handler(CurrentModel.java:150)
    at com.avaje.ebean.dbmigration.model.CurrentModel.createDdl(CurrentModel.java:141)
    at com.avaje.ebean.dbmigration.model.CurrentModel.getCreateDdl(CurrentModel.java:107)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.generateEvolutionScript(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:93)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$create$4(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:59)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1280)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.create(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:58)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:40)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:150)
```

The strange thing is, i don't use the Play Evolutions, i even disabled it in application.conf:

```
play.evolutions.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved the problem myself.

The Evolutions Module has to be disabled with an additional line in the config file, so i have this two lines in my application.conf now:

```
play.evolutions.enabled=false
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule"
```

I don't really get why this is needed and why it isn't documented in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions

Hopefully it will help someone in the future.